# Binding with ElementName in ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

As Documentation says, ResourceDictionary doesn't preserve any namespace names, so I can't bind using ElementName.How can I bind to textBox in WindowsPhone Framework, I don't see any solution, and I don't want to make AttachedProperty.

```
<Page.Resources>
<TextBox x:Key="sth" x:Name="textBox" >
    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Helpers:ExecuteCommandOnTextBoxEnterKeyBehavior
        CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=textBox}" Command="{Binding Command}"/>
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
</Page.Resources>
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

If your dictionary is inside Page.Resources then your page is in scope and you can reference elements on the page. If you remove it to a separate file then your page is no longer in scope.

Think of this like a private field in a C# class. It is available to anything inside the class. But other classes don't even know it is there, and cannot use it. Same concept.

If you need a solution then you need to include the data template in the resources of the page that holds the element to which you want to bind. Similar answer for code-behind.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I want to bind commandparameter to text of textBox.(or rather in opposite way) I don't see the point of data template here, what would I apply it to?

Comment: Ah, that's the heart of the question. CommandParameter cannot be bound. It's a known thing. Same in all versions of XAML, I think. Sorry. Has to be literal.

Comment: Of course it can be bound, it is like any other property. I is all about binding using ElementName=textBox, which is not possible in dictionary, but maybe there is a workaraund that i don't know of. If not I will have to cope with it in the less elegant way ;/

Comment: If elegance is what you seek, you should be passing the value through a view model. Binding directly to an element isn't a bad practice, but it certainly not elegant (or a best practice). If you have a view model then routing through it solves your problem.

Comment: At First I was binding to viewmodel, but it seemd wierd and inconvinient to have a lot of properties, which in fact were parameters for commands. I thought that if there are CommandParameters, then we should make use if them, and they do are good practice. Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: Btw Is having plenty of properties and commands in one view model normal ?

Comment: I believe you :) One thing you might consider is creating a third property that combines the two properties for the sake of the converter. But without seeing more of your code I better not make any more recommendations. ;)